# How to generate Pdf file from Word/Excel file using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to generate PDF files from Word Documents(.doc, .docx) or excel documents(.xls,.xlsx).
 I tried using ITextSharp but with that I am not able to render the images/tables etc of word document into the pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example of opening the word file using interops in VS2010 C#](http://omegacoder.com/?p=555)

I found this on [another website](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10013796/convert-word-document-into-a-pdf.aspx) hope it helps. Seems to be based around the plugin that is available for office to save as PDF.

> 'Save as PDF' add-on
>   for Office 2007, check out this link
>
> http://news.com.com/Microsoft+delivers+Save+as+PDF+add-on/2100-1012_3-6114752.html
>
> 2007 Microsoft Office Add-in:
>   Microsoft Save as PDF - download link
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=F1FC413C-6D89-4F15-991B-63B07BA5F2E5&displaylang=en
>
> Once you download this Addin, I think
>   you should be able to conver to PDF
>   using Word Objects in .NET.
>
> Otherwise,you have a third party
>   component written in .net which does
>   that for you, but the evaluation
>   version produces a watermark in the
>   converted documents, check the below
>   link and if you are ready to purchase
>   it then you can use it in your
>   vb.net/c#.net code to convert doc to
>   pdf
>
> http://www.aspose.com/Wiki/default.aspx/Aspose.Pdf/WordToPDF.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Office Interop to open the documents in Word/Excel, and publish to PDF (if you have 2007) or print using CutePDF Writer or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spire.Xls and Spire.Doc to do so.

Here is sample code.

```
    //xls to pdf        
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.LoadFromFile("sample.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2007);
    PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter(workbook);

    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
    pdfDocument.PageSettings.Orientation = PdfPageOrientation.Landscape;
    pdfDocument.PageSettings.Width = 970;
    pdfDocument.PageSettings.Height = 850;

    PdfConverterSettings settings = new PdfConverterSettings();
    settings.TemplateDocument = pdfDocument;
    pdfDocument = pdfConverter.Convert(settings);
    pdfDocument.SaveToFile("test.pdf");

    //doc to pdf
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.LoadFromFile("sample.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
    doc.SaveToFile("test.pdf", FileFormat.PDF);
```

Comment: what references do I need to compile this code ?

Comment: www.e-iceblue.com

Comment: it is not a free library :(

Comment: you could try this. https://github.com/dotnetcore/Magicodes.IE